# How to create site template with modern capabilities in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin, spfx, provider-hosted-app, site-design

I want to create a site template (lets say leave management system) with newly introduced "[Site Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/get-started-create-site-design)". With site design we can create lists, libraries with some set of columns, installing add-in etc. But I cannot create pages and I cannot push the web part to pages.

With SPFx we cannot create pages, we cannot add web parts to the pages (remaining things can be done).

Question is:

How to deploy lists, libraries, pages, web parts in a single package using modern capabilities in SharePoint like site design, SPFx, MS Flow or any other etc.

Is there a way to achieve in Provider Hosted apps(creating lists, creating pages, installing SPFx, pushing modern web parts to pages)?

Answer (score 2):

PNP recently added capabilities for working with modern pages to their core javascript library and their powershell commands. For example, the [Add-PnPClientSideWebPart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpclientsidewebpart?view=sharepoint-ps) powershell command allows you to add a web part to a modern page.

So, all you'd have to do is create an azure function that uses the pnp powershell to add the desired web parts, and call the azure function from a flow that was configure to run as part of the site design. Here's a [blog post](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/03/16/creating-sharepoint-modern-team-sites-using-site-scripts-flow-and-azure-function/) that walks through it, with an additional piece of an azure storage queue.

As a side note, hopefully microsoft improves this situation, as this is a ridiculous amount of work to add web parts to page, especially considering that this reproduces functionality available via clicking on "save site as template"

Answer (score 1):

You can use PnP templates in Microsoft Flow to provision SharePoint entities.

[This article](https://medium.com/plumsail/create-sharepoint-sites-lists-libraries-using-pnp-templates-and-microsoft-flow-7bb05c60bd8a) describes how to provision sites, lists, libraries, and Modern pages using PnP templates from Microsoft Flow.

Note, this is provided as an action in the Plumsail SP connector, which is a part of [Plumsail Actions](https://plumsail.com/actions/) product. It is a paid product.

[image]